# How to scrape image urls of comments?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Following code scrapes comments and customer country from each product page for example this product from [aliexpress website](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003801507855.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1e951bc72xISfE&algo_pvid=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad&algo_exp_id=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad-8&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000027213624098%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B40.81%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BMAD%3Bsearch-mainSearch)

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003801507855.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1e951bc72xISfE&algo_pvid=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad&algo_exp_id=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad-8&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000027213624098%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B40.81%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BMAD%3Bsearch-mainSearch'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tab-content'))))
driver.get(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#product-evaluation'))).get_attribute('src'))

data=[]

while True:

    for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.feedback-item'):

        try:
            country = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-country > b').text
        except:
            country = None

        try:
            comment = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.buyer-feedback span').text
        except:
            comment = None

        data.append({
            'country':country,
            'comment':comment
        })
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#complex-pager a.ui-pagination-next'))).click()
    except:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('filename.csv',index=False)
```

I need to have a code that scrape url of images available in each comment of customers, but I really don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in the same way as with `comment` and `country` so simply add a new `try/except` to add a list of image urls to your dict:

```
try:
    images = [i.get_attribute('src') for i in e.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.r-photo-list img')]
except:
    images = []

data.append({
    'country':country,
    'comment':comment,
    'images':images
})
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003801507855.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1e951bc72xISfE&algo_pvid=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad&algo_exp_id=6d3ed61e-f378-43d0-a429-5f6cddf3d6ad-8&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000027213624098%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B40.81%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BMAD%3Bsearch-mainSearch'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tab-content'))))
driver.get(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#product-evaluation'))).get_attribute('src'))

data=[]

while True:

    for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.feedback-item'):

        try:
            country = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-country > b').text
        except:
            country = None

        try:
            comment = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.buyer-feedback span').text
        except:
            comment = None

        try:
            images = [i.get_attribute('src') for i in e.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.r-photo-list img')]
        except:
            images = []

        data.append({
            'country':country,
            'comment':comment,
            'images':images
        })
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#complex-pager a.ui-pagination-next'))).click()
    except:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('filename.csv',index=False)
```

##### Output

| country | comment | images |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ES | ICH empfehlen sie, ICH geliebt sie und sie arbeiten sehr gut. | ['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ue579837c61094df2af612e27b3f5b415R.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/U3fd665774a6d4aebbee85d35da080350f.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/U18d93ae3598c482e8023d0663e0a6fc9U.jpg'] |
| TR | Angekommen in Der Türkei so bald wie 10 tage ICH hatte gekauft für meine mutter nicht wie zu hören sehr laut erfüllt die erwartung. Ganz tiny und süße dank verkäufer. | ['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ue4dc72f3a91b43248ad6ae2f4444e5b9g.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/U1ec20cd1f09f421a80a96d6a6cc0d6a7C.jpg'] |
| RU | Die besten kopfhörer! Sehr lange halten die batterie! Super design!! | [] |
| MA |  | ['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ua0c22f565f0648c7943169ffbb74dd792.jpg'] |
| SA | It is an amazing, good for use…!!!! | ['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/U000b27dca5874bd681c6e285b69e0e71p.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/U0020e8a4147047ec9646cf64bb7b18cay.jpg'] |
| SA | Gute | [] |
| CL | Sie sind kleine, ICH nicht versucht es noch. | [] |